# What literary device is used in from "one thing to another"?

Tags: short-stories, french-language, literary-device, alphonse-daudet

The extract is

> Then, from one thing to another, M. Hamel went on to talk of the French language, saying that it was the most beautiful language in the world — the clearest, the most logical; that we must guard it among us and never forget it, because when a people are enslaved, as long as they hold fast to their language it is as if they had the key to their prison. Then he opened a grammar and read us our lesson.

It is a translation given to us from  Alphonse Daudet's *La Dernière Classe* (translated as [The Last Lesson](https://ncert.nic.in/textbook.php?lefl1=1-14) in an NCERT textbook).

Please help me to identify the literary device  in

> from one thing to another

Answer (score 2):

In the French text ([La Dernière classe](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Les_Contes_du_lundi/La_Derni%C3%A8re_classe) on Wikisource), we find the same type of construction:

> Alors **d'une chose à l'autre**, M. Hamel se mit à nous parler de la langue française, …

What is missing here is a verb, as in "*moving* from one thing to the next". [Ellipsis](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/learn/glossary-terms/ellipsis) is a poetic device that can be used when leaving out a word does not impede understanding of the text, but it is hard to argue that leaving out the verb is done here for poetic effect.

What we see here is an [elliptical construction](https://glossary.sil.org/term/elliptical-construction), which SIL's Glossary of Linguistic Terms defines as follows:

> An elliptical construction is a construction that lacks an element that is recoverable or inferable from the context.

In the phrase "from one thing to another", we can easily infer a verb such as "move" but the phrase is still understandable without it. This is a normal linguistic phenomenon rather than a literary device.

---

Response to one of Karthik's comments: there is no example of  metaphor, personification, allusion or hyperbole in this phrase. Mr. Hamel's description of the French language as "the most beautiful language in the world — the clearest, the most logical" is an example of excessive praise. And as verbose pointed out in a comment, "they hold fast to their language it is **as if they had the key to their prison**" is a metaphor.

Comment: I am given four options in my text 1) metaphor 2) Personification 3) allusion 4) hyperbole
I think that it is not a hyperbole since hyperbole exaggerates things. It does not seem like allusion either.

Comment: @Karthik I don't see how it can be any of the devices listed by your textbook. Other than leaving out a verb, I don't see anything special about the phrase "from one thing to another".

Comment: That is why i got confused. This came in my examination. When revising, just saw this. Got doubts and posted here.

Comment: @Karthik This is not the first time that such questions are asked here. Unfortunately, exam preparation books sometimes contain confusing answers or even errors. See the questions tagged [tag:sat-ii-success-literature], where this also came up.

Comment: This isn't verb phrase ellipsis: "the ellipsis must be introduced by an auxiliary verb *(be, can, do, don't, could, have, may, might, shall, should, will, won't, would, etc.)* or by the infinitive particle *to*." (And as far as I can tell, VPE is not a phenomenon in French at all?) The phrase just a word-for-word translation of a perfectly normal French construction which reads oddly in English.

Comment: Calling it the poetic device of ellipsis doesn't seem to fit either. Rhetorical devices are used for effect. There's no poetic effect achieved by leaving out the verb here; and in any case, I don't think it's grammatically necessary to posit a missing verb here at all.

Comment: @verbose I would expect a verb there, though. Both in French and in English. Without a verb, it is an elliptical clause.

Comment: h'm I certainly don't miss one in English. I can see that one would fit there, but its absence doesn't strike me as odd.

Comment: @Karthik if the entire passage you have quoted is part of your question, then " it is as if they had the key to their prison" is a metaphor. If the question is about just the "from one thing to another" bit, Tsundoku is right and none of the options fit.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a literary device. It means exactly what it says. M. Hamel has been telling Franz that he should not blame himself for slacking in his schoolwork. The story continues:

> Then, passing from one thing to another, Monsieur Hamel began to talk to us about the French language.

He is literally changing the subject, from Franz’s lack of diligence to the French language, so he is “passing from one thing to another.”

Your question leaves out the word *passing*. I am not sure whether you misquoted, or whether you are looking at a different translation from the one at Bartleby, but in any case, the meaning is straightforward and literal, not metaphoric or rhetorical.

Comment: Yeah, it is not a translation from bartley [The link] (https://ncert.nic.in/textbook.php?lefl1=1-14)

Comment: @Karthik great, good to know. But the answer is the same. No literary device, he’s just moving from one topic to another.

Answer (score -1):

One can argue that it's a *metaphor*, in that he is not physically moving from one place to another, but changing topics.  However, this metaphor is so commonplace as to qualify as an idiom, having acquired the literal meaning that once it meant metaphorically.